# Download Python 32 bit for Mac

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I want to run modules such as CV2 and numpy in my code, but I don't think it will work without 32 bit Python. So I want to download 32 bit python (IDLE) but I'm not sure how to on my Mac.

Comment: You go to the Python website and download it? Where exactly is your problem?

Comment: Did you perform a search in Google or Bing for "Python 32 bit for Mac" before asking? You basically need to decide what version of 32-bit Python you need first, then worry about the modules because they're usually version-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Both those packages should work with all versions of python 3. You can check the version of python installed on your Mac by opening Terminal and then entering `python --version`. If it's python 3, you should be good to go. If you see `command not found` or something similar, go to the python website and download.

Next, check that pip (python's default package installer) is also installed correctly. In terminal, enter `pip --version`. You should see something other than `command not found`.

Both numpy and cv2 are python packages and will need to be imported in your code. You've likely done this already with python's native (pre-installed packages) like datetime etc. However, neither numpy nor cv2 are pre-installed packages, so you'll have to use pip to install them. Once you've confirmed pip is installed (above), enter `pip install cv2` and then `pip install numpy`. You should then be able to import them and use them in your code